# Running executable from java fails

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to run mdb-export on a file I know exist in that directory. But it does not seem to execute. "ls-l" will so I am sure that the java code is working. The command will execute perfectly from bash.

The failing command is

```
/usr/bin/mdb-export -Q -d ';' -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' /home/jocke/viking.mdb resultat >> resultat.csv

    private void runCommand() {
        try {
            String workingdirectory=System.getProperty("user.dir"); 
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            //Process process = runtime.exec("/usr/bin/mdb-export -Q -d ';' -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' /home/jocke/viking.mdb resultat >> resultat.csv");
            Process process = runtime.exec("/usr/bin/mdb-export /home/jocke/viking.mdb resultat >> resultat.csv");
            //
            process.waitFor();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use 'exec(String)', use exec(String[])'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use output redirection this way. Use a `ProcessBuilder` instead:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/mdb-export", "/home/jocke/viking.mdb", "resultat");
File csv = new File("resultat.csv");
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(csv);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work. Just getting exitCode = 1. But I just made an export.sh and run that instead. Works like expected.

Comment: Seems like it's this part that creates the problem. -Q -d ';' -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'